# Checkbox onclick is not working in IE8 but working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating dynamic checkbox and attaching onclick event with that. Below is the code:

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
checkbox.onclick = testClick();
cell1.appendChild(checkbox);

function testClick() {
            alert("Hello");
}
```

The above piece of code is working fine with IE9 but not with IE8. I'm using Jquery 1.7.1.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, why not use it? That takes care of cross browser issues

```
$(domElement).click(function(){
    // do your thing here
});
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't take care of syntax errors though... clearly binding the return value of a function as a callback function is not the way to go

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Wrapping the function call in an anonymous function will take care of that, though.

Comment: True, but that's a bit overkill, isn't it? creating an anonymous callback because that just calls a function rather defeats the point of callbacks, to my mind :P

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem it is basically the same thing. You are also creating a callback function. I would suggest a rewrite of your code to jQuery, if you use it anyway.

Comment: I know you're creating a callback when you do it your way. It seems I came across all wrong. I merely meant to make a little side note... that and I like to use `this.someProperty` in the body of my actual callback function, which is not possible this way, unless you call the function like so: `testClick.call(this);`. But again, that's just typing a lot more than just the function name... In programming, it's ok to be lazy IMO

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass function handler, not function call to `onclick` attribute:

```
checkbox.onclick = testClick;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working (means I'm not getting any error in IE8 now) but in the testClick method I have an alert which is coming fine in IE9 but not in IE8.